# javascript regex lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regex

```
^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}(\([a-z]\))?(\(\d\))?$
```

to match the values like (a)(6),(b)(4)
This works fine. But I need to test just (a) as true, but just (3) should return false. 
I wanted something like

```
^\d{1,2}\.\d{1,3}(\([a-z]\))?(?(-1)\(\d\))?$
```

I read somewhere that javascript doesnt support lookbehind. 
I need to match a pattern as follows.

- 23.456       -> true
- 23.346(f)    -> true
- 23.378(5)    -> false
- 23.214(b)(7) -> true

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: What you read was correct :)

Comment: What do you really want?

Comment: I think the OP means the 1st group must exist, 2nd group is optional.

Comment: Well, I need to match a pattern as follows. \n 23.456 -> true \n 23.346(f)->true \n 23.378(5) -> false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this may work for you:

```
^\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,3}([(][a-z][)]([(][0-9][)])?)?$
```

Note that i prefer `[.]` syntax over the default escape`\.` one.

**Legenda**  <kbd>[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fV1zT8/2)</kbd>

```
^\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,3} # this may be also [\d.] if you don't care about structure
(                  # START GROUP 1
  [(][a-z][)]      # A lowercase letter inside round bracket
  (                # START GROUP 2
    [(]\d[)]       # A digit inside round bracket
  )?               # END GROUP 2: make it optional
)?                 # END GROUP 1: make it optional
$                  # End of the string
```

**Live Demo**

```js
// Add /i at bottom to make the regex it case insensitive
var re = /^\d{1,2}[.]\d{1,3}([(][a-z][)]([(][0-9][)])?)?$/; 

var tests = ['23.456','23.346(f)','23.378(5)','23.214(b)(7)'].reverse();
var m;

while( t = tests.pop() ) {
    document.write('"' + t + '"<br/>');
    document.write('Valid? ' + ( (t.match(re)) ? '<font color="green">YES</font>' : '<font color="red">NO</font>') + '<br/><br/>');
}
```

Comment: Awesome. That was really helpful. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You'll need this regex:

```
\([a-z]\)(\(\d\))?$
```

- `(a)(3)` - true
- `(a)` - true
- `(3)` - false

Comment: Thanks. But there is something else before this match as well. which is mandatory. But \([a-z]\) and \(\d\) are optional

Comment: can you give some examples?

Comment: I just updated the question. 23.456 -> true  23.346(f)->true  23.378(5) -> false 23.214(b)(7)->true